# PUSH/PULL ZMQ Socket

Tags: socket

I'm writing a PUSH/PULL ZMQ architecture. I've already written PUB/SUB where PUB binds in Python and sends data to SUB in Mathematica. However, I'd like to write a PUSH/PULL where both the socket binding and connection occurs in Mathematica. What functionality is used to accomplish this binding. I've tried `SocketConnect[ip, {"ZMQ", "PUSH"}]` and `SocketConnect[ip, {"ZMQ", "PULL"}]` on other end, but I am confused as to executing the PULL to receive the data. Any suggestions?